# Why did I have to use `ESCAPE_NON_ASCII` to parse µ?

Tags: java, json, jackson, jackson-databind

From service `Sender`, I'm sending a JSON with the character µ (UTF-8 code: `0xb5`) inside one of the strings, like so:

```json
{
   "apiserver.latency.k8s.io/response-write":"1.446µs"
}
```

I'm including the content-type header as `"application/json;charset=UTF-8"` in the request.

This string is initially held in POJO, so in order to send the payload to `Receiver` service I'm using Jackson to convert it to `String`, like so:

```java
// myPojo is an object containing the `µ` in one of its members 
String body = objectMapper.writeValueAsString(myPojo)
ResponseEntity<String> response = restClient.postForEntity(url, body,
                    String.class);
```

However, the `Receiver` service fails the request after throwing the following exception:

```
com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb5
```

If I configure the `ObjectMapper` with the following:

```java
objectMapper.getFactory().configure(JsonWriteFeature.ESCAPE_NON_ASCII.mappedFeature(), true);
```

The `Receiver` service now successfully parses the request, and lets it through.

However from what I've read, Jackson always produces valid JSON. So how come I have to enable the above setting for the request to go through? Further, it seems `µ` is a valid UTF-8 character, which is Jackson's default encoding, so why is it failing?

This is how I'm reading the payload in a custom deserializer:

```java
public class JsonToStringValueDeserializer extends JsonDeserializer<String> {

    private static final TypeReference<JsonNode> JSON_NODE_TYPE = new TypeReference<>(){};

    @Override
    public String deserialize(JsonParser p, DeserializationContext ctx) throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
        String retVal;

        if (p.currentToken().isStructStart()) {
            JsonNode val = p.readValueAs(JSON_NODE_TYPE);
            retVal = val.toString();
        } else {
            retVal = p.readValueAs(String.class);
        }

        return retVal;
    }
}
```

This is because I want this part of the payload to be deserialized as `String` in `Receiver`, regardless of how the sender initially sent it (we have another `Sender2` sending this part of the payload as a base64 string).

Comment: When you say "UTF-8 code: `0xb5`", do you mean "Unicode code point `0xb5`" or "UTF-8 encoded: `0xb5`"?

Comment: *com.fasterxml.jackson.core.JsonParseException: Invalid UTF-8 start byte 0xb5* might well be a sign that your platform encoding on which you're working is not UTF-8. The micro sign is encoded as `C2 B5` in UTF-8, not `B5`

Comment: @Sören my knowledge of the subject is very limited, I simply meant to say that when I looked up `µ`'s `UTF-8` code, it said `0xb5`, which is also the character my receiving service was complaining about.

Comment: @g00se I think you are right, and my previous comment to Soren is incorrect.

Comment: So micro **can** be represented both by `UTF-8` and [some-other-encoding], but since Jackson is assuming `UTF-8` when it's serializing the String, it leaves `0xb5` alone...?

Comment: If you were to do `byte[] a = "1.446µs".getBytes();IntStream.range(0, a.length).map(i -> a[i]).forEach(i -> System.out.printf("%02X ", 0xFF & i));` you would probably find it prints `31 2E 34 34 36 B5 73`

Comment: UTF-8 can represent essentially anything. 8 bit encodings are limited. I can't say what Jackson is doing as I don't know it well but basically it looks like it's playing safe for characters that are not common to 'all' charsets. In your case it succeeds. You have a deeper problem with your environment so I'm guessing you're using Windows

Comment: @g00se I'm not sure what's happening either. I'm on Linux on all services. I also don't understand what "playing it safe" means. I guess this specific string is just not UTF-8, so I now have to figure out what is the encoding of the original string (I'm receiving it from a 3rd-party)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/255056/discussion-between-g00se-and-shibel).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user g00se's comments led me in the right direction: Our sending service is based on Spring, and our version/as of today Spring’s default `StringHttpMessageConverter` encodes the payload in ISO-8859-1.